# How to generate Java classes from Json File?

Tags: java, json, parsing, code-generation, auto-generate

I would like to knows if someone can show me the right way to generate Java classes from a json File ?

for example if we have the following json file :

```
{
  "Personne": {
    "Name": "Job Moun ",
    "Phone": "062352665566"
  }
}
```

I want to generate Java code automatically, something like that :

```
public class Personne{

private String Name;
private String phone;

....
}
```

Comment: see : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/bind/jaxb-json-example/

Comment: There are many (online) tools available. Example: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Lots of frameworks exist that will solve this problem for you. Jackson ( https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson ) and GSON (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) are both worth looking at and both make this pretty easy.

Comment: @yahyaelfakir generate a class file not the object, read the question

Comment: It's not as simple as your example, but Swagger has quite a few export options once you define the objects: http://editor.swagger.io

Comment: If you have node.js and npm installed, you can take a look at this package: https://github.com/rtoshiro/json2poxo

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at this online tool if it's sufficient for you:

https://javafromjson.dashingrocket.com

or use some templating engine like Velocity in conjunction with Jackson library for reading JSON. Here you have some basic functionality:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Comment: These links are long down